# Javascript window.open() with php code (true popup)

Tags: javascript, php, popup, window.open

I am trying to have a window popup from a hyperlink.

I have my window with a hyperlink on which I want to open a popup with the OnClick event.

I am using PHP with javascipt.

OK first code with first symptoms.

```
echo '<a href="" onclick="javascript:void window.open(this.href, '\1436971878137\','\width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0, resizable=0,left=0,top=0\');return false;">Edit</a>'
```

It doesn't open a popup, it just refreshes the hosting page, so not what I want.

Now other code, other symptoms:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.google.fr" onclick="javascript:void window.open(this.href,'\1436971878137\','\width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0\');return false;">Edit</a>'
```

It changes my hosting page for google, so it is not a popup either.... So not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for: having a popup, but I tried many many things before asking here, without success. So I am hoping somebody could help me on this.
Actually google is here just for the example, in my real application it will be a PHP page with a formular on it....

[Edit : ]  What I want is a small popup in the same window, like when you do a rightclick on desktop you have a small popup with menus, see? I don't want a popup that does open in a new tab, this is not what I want. I am looking for a small popup in the page I am in.
Many thanks for your replies !

Comment: Even though you're using php, this isn't a PHP question, as your code could just be `?><a href="path">link</a><?php` taking php out of the equation completely. I would edit your question to reflect this and you'll get more relevant people seeing this question. Also, is `target="_blank"` what you're looking for?

Comment: Why didn't you put the javascript in the href? The `javascript:` keyword is not right inside an onclick (which already expects javascript). The whole point of `javascript:` is to put javascript in an href (which doesn't normally expect it).

Comment: You should prevent the default on click behavior too because the default behavior of the `<a>` tag is to go to the defined address.

Comment: Hello all, well, I did try the javascript in href, not working either.  I tried this:        echo '<a href=javascript:void window.open(\'www.google.fr\',
         \'myWindow\',\'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=0,
         resizable=0,left=0,top=0\');return false;">Edit
       </a>';                                                              it just doesn't do anything

Comment: hi Goose, sorry, I don't understand where I should put target="_blank", could you please be more specific? Many thanks

Comment: You MUST NOT insert JavaScript code in `href`, the same with the use of `a` tag if it's not a hyperlink. If you don't want to provide a fallback for people without JavaScript, you should use other element, such as `span` and, if you wish, style it to look like a link. Semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far so good, here is the solution to have a real popup, not a new page and not a refresh of the hosting page. Here we go !

```
echo '<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'formulaire.php\',\'windowname1\', \'width=600, height=500\'); return false;">Edit</a>';
```